# Connect Amazon EC2 to my Local MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, macos, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to do the following?:

I have a local Mac running OS X Lion with a MySQL Server installed which runs different processes regularly and stores data into a local DB.

On the other hand I have an Amazon EC2 instance.

What I would like to do is to use the Amazon instance to perform certain cronjobs (using its own resources) but connecting to the data that is on my localhost (my computer) and performing basic SQL actions like updating the data, inserting, etc.

I don't know if this helps, but I have a static IP. Is there any way I can "open" my IP so the Amazon instance can recognize my home computer as a valid MySQL server?

Thanks for your help, any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your EC2 instance is connecting to your local db you'll need a static IP locally. Well not need... but if you don't have it anytime you reset your router or loose power etc your ip will change. You can look into Dynamic DNS as well for your local instance.

Your ISP will not block your port on your local instance. This would be a firewall inside your network that is preventing you from connecting to mysql or a configuration with mysql itself. Users can only connect to mysql from certain IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks, what I am not understanding is which will be the IP I will tell the EC2 instance to connect to? I have the public static IP my ISP gives me, and locally I have 3 different machines, the DB is on one of them 192.168.0.1 lets say. Thanks again!

Comment: Log into your database machine and go to http://ipchicken.com that will give you the IP of that machine. Unless you have some router configuration that redirects that ip somewhere else that should be the correct ip to use. Any ip address that starts with 192.168.x.x is a local ip address amazon cannot connect to that ip.

Comment: Thanks for that,it worked! I thought it was going to be much more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to open up the mysql port on your firewall if you are using one, have the mysql client installed on your EC2 instance, and make sure that the user that had proper grantable permissions.

That said why not run cron locally on the mac?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So basically I need to ask my ISP to let me open port 3306? and thats it? I was reading about VPN , lion server, and all that, I don't need anything of that?

The reason I need to run the crons on a different machine is that my local machine can't handle any more work, thats why I thought on outsourcing resources to an ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login to your server via SSH then there's no need to open any other port and no static IP is required. You can use SSH port forwarding instead. From your local machine run:

```
ssh -C -R 5555:127.0.0.1:3306 <your-server-host>
```

Now you should be able to connect to your Mac's database running on `localhost:3306` from the remote server at `localhost:5555`.